# How to delete last two lines of an output using AWK?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, ksh, nawk

i am trying to make a graphic representation of an output that shows the free memory of the server of the current day (which is shown approximetaly by hour), from that output i dont want the first two lines and last two, the first two i can easy delete with the NR, though i have had trouble with the last two, the only way i found was to reverse the whole output delete the first two lines and then reverse it again to its normal state.

Any better/correct way to delete the last two lines but do it inside the AWK?

this is what i have so far and works fine.

```
echo 'graphics (freemem)'
echo 'GiB      0      500k      1M      1,5M'
sar -r | tail -r | awk 'NR > 2{ print }' | tail -r | nawk '
    NR > 4{
    LINE = sprintf("%" int(($2 / 100000)*2 )"s", " "); 
    gsub(/ /, "#", LINE);
    print $1, LINE; } 
'
```

**UPDATE**

So i did it in another way because it would easier the script to read and it works for me, but for any other guy that needs to do that use either the previous way i did it, or the ways that the guys below have answered.

```
echo 'graphics (freemem)'
echo 'GiB      0      500k      1M      1,5M'
sar -r | nawk '
    NR > 4 && $1 !~ /Average/ && $1 !~ /^$/ {
    LINE = sprintf("%" int(($2 * 2) / 100000 )"s", " "); 
    gsub(/ /, "#", LINE);
    print $1, LINE; } 
'
```

**UPDATE 2**

So what i want to make is a graphic representation of data monitored, this output updates about each hour, keep in mind that in different hours of the day the length of the rows vary. So this the actual ouput of `sar -r` that i get.

```
.
SunOS doc 5.10

00:00:00 freemem freeswap
01:00:01 1624430 19474799
02:00:00 1624421 19474738
03:00:00 1624413 19474683
04:00:00 1624527 19475309
05:00:00 1624525 19475290
06:00:00 1624517 19475232
07:00:01 1624510 19475176
08:00:00 1624503 19475120
08:20:00 1539793 18771472
08:40:00 1509924 18535201
09:00:00 1500681 18492050
09:20:00 1494254 18435535
09:40:00 1479623 18266664
10:00:00 1486372 18317241
10:20:00 1480565 18269032
10:40:00 1479030 18260247
11:00:01 1476462 18237731
11:20:00 1475999 18234221
11:40:00 1478854 18259827
12:00:00 1478223 18254861
12:20:00 1482956 18294572
12:40:00 1479061 18260565
13:00:00 1470463 18185441
13:20:00 1474090 18217961
13:40:00 1478585 18257393
14:00:00 1478219 18255445
14:20:00 1474327 18223749
14:40:00 1470468 18190676
15:00:00 1471941 18204282
15:20:00 1474138 18223380
15:40:00 1471698 18202561
16:00:00 1470316 18191099
16:20:00 1467203 18163653
16:40:00 1468943 18179148

Average  1549994 18855701
```

So we dont care about freeswap and we dont use that. We care only for the results of freemem. So what i am trying to do is take as entry that column and "translate" the number into " # " through a calculation so i can later specify the amount of data in the graphic representation. Though, there are rows in the start and in the end of the output that i dont need so i need them deleted.

This is the working code i have now

```
echo '\ngraphics (freemem)'
echo 'GiB      0      500k      1M      1,5M'
sar -r | awk 'NR > 2 {print P2} {P2=P; P=$0}' |
nawk '
    NR > 4 {
    LINE = sprintf("%" int(($2 * 2) / 100000 )"s", " "); 
    gsub(/ /, "#", LINE);
    print $1, LINE; } 
'
```

so the correct output is this one:

```
graphics (freemem)
GiB      0      500k      1M      1,5M
01:00:01 ################################
02:00:00 ################################
03:00:00 ################################
04:00:00 ################################
05:00:00 ################################
06:00:00 ################################
07:00:01 ################################
08:00:00 ################################
08:20:00 ##############################
08:40:00 ##############################
09:00:00 ##############################
09:20:00 #############################
09:40:00 #############################
10:00:00 #############################
10:20:00 #############################
10:40:00 #############################
11:00:01 #############################
11:20:00 #############################
11:40:00 #############################
12:00:00 #############################
12:20:00 #############################
12:40:00 #############################
13:00:00 #############################
13:20:00 #############################
13:40:00 #############################
14:00:00 #############################
14:20:00 #############################
14:40:00 #############################
15:00:00 #############################
15:20:00 #############################
15:40:00 #############################
16:00:00 #############################
16:20:00 #############################
```

Comment: what about piping to  `head -n -2`?

Comment: i tried that and it didnt work, it gives me this error                                   `head: option requires an argument -- n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the line, do things and print after a while so that you can know if you are in the last line or not. But that is too much golfing when you have tools like `head` and `tail`.

Just pipe the output to `head` before passing it to `awk`:

```
head -n -2
```

#### Test

```
$ seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ seq 10 | head -n -2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

---

Since you don't have a GNU head allowing you to do this, you can hold the variables with `awk`:

```
awk '{if (prev_prev_line) print prev_prev_line; prev_prev_line=prev_line}
     {prev_line=$0}'
```

This shifts lines, so that you have in `prev_prev_line` the content of the line you had two lines ago:

```
NR      $0    prev_line   prev_prev_line
 1      1      -             -
 2      2      1             -
 3      3      2             1
 4      4      3             2
 ....
 NR-1   NR-1   NR-2          NR-3
 NR     NR     NR-1          NR-2
```

So since you are working with `prev_prev_line`, you will end up handling from the 1st to the `(NR-2)`th line.

So in `prev_prev_line` you have the line that occurred two lines ago. This way, you do not use the last two lines in the output.

See how it works with an example:

```
$ awk '{if (prev_prev_line) print NR,prev_prev_line; prev_prev_line=prev_line}
         {prev_line=$0}' < <(seq 10)
3 1
4 2
5 3
6 4
7 5
8 6
9 7
10 8
```

Comment: just answered u the same thing on ur comment, i tried that already and it didnt work, it gives me this error `head: option requires an argument -- n`

Comment: so the whole code would be like this: 
`echo 'graphics (freemem)'
echo 'GiB      0      50k      100k      150k'
sar -r | head -n -2 | nawk '
 NR > 4{
 LINE = sprintf("%" int(($2 / 100000)*2 )"s", " "); 
 gsub(/ /, "#", LINE);
 print $1, LINE; } 
'`

Comment: What if you try `head --lines -2`? Both work to me in GNU head.

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos too bad... See my update with `awk`. It is a matter of holding the line that occurred two lines ago.

Comment: i was kind of hoping that there is something like NR that i used but for deleting rows in the end of the output....

Comment: i think i understand what you did there with the awk, but could you please explain it a bit? tnx in advance :)

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos see the updated answer with an example. Do some tests locally as well to fully understand it, even though it is just a matter of "moving" lines backwards.

Comment: thanks a lot man, your answer covered me, if none else has a way to do this with one command i am raising the flag/tick  for u :)

Comment: @SkatZ this answer deserves an up tick, but I did post how to do it in one line.

Comment: @SaintHax man i also commented your answer, problem with your one line solution is that its for a file, and second of all i was looking for a command to add in nawk, not a line :p

Comment: That will fail if/when the output contains blank lines and/or lines that evaluate numerically to zero.

Comment: @EdMorton you are right. I think I made it way too complicated: I started with something similar to yours `NR>2` but then got obfuscated.

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos take a look at Ed Morton's answer, it makes things easier!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'NR>2{print p2} {p2=p; p=$0}'
1
2
3
```

Given your edited question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    print "\ngraphics (freemem)"
    print "GiB      0      500k      1M      1,5M"
}
/^[0-9: ]+$/ {
    line = sprintf("%*s", int(($2*2)/100000), "")
    gsub(/ /,"#",line)
    print $1, line
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file

graphics (freemem)
GiB      0      500k      1M      1,5M
01:00:01 ################################
02:00:00 ################################
03:00:00 ################################
04:00:00 ################################
05:00:00 ################################
06:00:00 ################################
07:00:01 ################################
08:00:00 ################################
08:20:00 ##############################
08:40:00 ##############################
09:00:00 ##############################
09:20:00 #############################
09:40:00 #############################
10:00:00 #############################
10:20:00 #############################
10:40:00 #############################
11:00:01 #############################
11:20:00 #############################
11:40:00 #############################
12:00:00 #############################
12:20:00 #############################
12:40:00 #############################
13:00:00 #############################
13:20:00 #############################
13:40:00 #############################
14:00:00 #############################
14:20:00 #############################
14:40:00 #############################
15:00:00 #############################
15:20:00 #############################
15:40:00 #############################
16:00:00 #############################
16:20:00 #############################
16:40:00 #############################
```

Comment: so this is like what  @fedorqui did? you print the row after the next one so that the last two wouldnt get printed?

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos yes, only that this is safer.

Comment: @fedorqui actually i just tried it, and it is not doing it, it doesnt give an error, but the last two lines are still there... propably a stupid question, but it would work only in awk right?? it wouldnt work in nawk i suppose???

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos what exact command are you running?

Comment: just tried this one...
`echo 'graphics (freemem)'

echo 'GiB      0      50k      100k      150k'

sar -r |
nawk '

 {print p2} {p2=p; p=$0} NR > 4{

 LINE = sprintf("%" int(($2 * 2) / 100000 )"s", " "); 

 gsub(/ /, "#", LINE);
 print $1, LINE; } 
'`

Comment: no man its not hard i can understand what you are doing there, but problem is its not doing it :p

Comment: what you mean i didnt copy the code... first of all i changed the NR > 2 to NR > 4, second of all, the NR exists after i added your code, on the code i added 3 comments up....  third of all, i just added your code inside the nawk that i used so i wouldnt have to pipe one more awk... but first of all everything gets printed twice, which i dont want and plus the last two lines dont get deleted. only if i put the code like this it works... but if i do it like that, then i have to use NR > 6 because for some reason that creates 2 more empty lines in the top of the output...

Comment: `echo '\ngraphics (freemem)'
echo 'GiB      0      50k      100k      150k'
sar -r | awk '{print p2} {p2=p; p=$0}' |
nawk '
 NR > 6{
 LINE = sprintf("%" int(($2 * 2) / 100000 )"s", " "); 
 gsub(/ /, "#", LINE);
 print $1, LINE; } 
'`

Comment: and still even if i put it like you want it so i would put the NR > 2 with your code and leave the other NR > 2 in my nawk then i get two empty rows in the top, so i have to use NR > 4 plus your NR > 2, so wouldnt it be correct  if i would just use a NR > 6.....

Comment: Yeah man i can understand what is the difference, and i know what each code does...... and yes i can see the difference, i was just pointing out though what i wanted to do, and what happens if i try to do what i wanted with the code you gave me... get it now? anyways, ill just pop it in a new awk before my nawk and its fine...

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution given your updated question.

Comment: yeah i just saw and really tnx for your time spent here, though i copied everything, and called it with awk, and it didnt work on my machine....

Comment: `it didnt work` is just about the worst thing you can tell someone trying to help you as it's immensely frustrating to be told something `didn't work` with absolutely zero information that might help you figure out what went wrong. It's like taking your car to the mechanic and telling him `it doesn't work` and expecting him to fix it based on just that. Always state in what way it didn't work (wrong output, no output, error message, something else...), your awk version (path to it and `awk --version` output), the box your on (Solaris?), etc. The script I posted will work in any modern awk.

Answer (score 2):

if nothing else works

```
... | sed '$d' | sed '$d'
```

Comment: this sollution is like better than mine i suppose, but worst than awk.... still tnx for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Escape out of the awk to do some math on the file

```
awk '{if (NR > 2 && NR < '$(( $(wc -l <$file) -1))')print $0}' $file
```

If the record number is greater than 2, we've skipped the first 2 lines.  If it's less than the total lines minus 1, we've stopped before the last two (you could use -2, if you use <=).

Comment: problem here is that i dont want make these changes to a file but to a specific column that is printed out of an output.

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos I'm confused-- why don't you just put your awk commands that you need in place of the "print $0".  Your request was to not print the first 2 or last 2 lines.  So that is what I gave you.

Comment: no man, i didnt say either that or that, i said i want both to be deleted, and i said that the first two i can easily do with NR but for the last two i couldnt find a command like NR ..... thats what i said....